# problem in default argument in JavaScript's function

Tags: javascript, function

I have created a JavaScript Function with a default argument `remove = false` but when No value is passed the remove parameter do not acquire the default "false" value instead of that it acquires a very large object, See my  Function code:-

```
infoBtnCB.addEventListener("click", clickEventInfoBtn_CB);
function clickEventInfoBtn_CB(remove = false) {
  console.log(remove);
  if (remove) {
    infoBtnCB.classList.remove("active-info-btn-CB");
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.classList.toggle("active-info-btn-CB");
  }
  if (infoBtnCB.innerHTML == "Info" && !remove) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      infoBtnCB.innerHTML =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque accusamus ipsum, quidem harum similique blanditiis, veritatis nam sapiente tenetur rerum temporibus asperiores, commodi consequatur corporis quisquam aspernatur quas laudantium eaque.m";
    }, 100);
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.innerHTML = "Info";
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT WHEN FUNCTION IS CALLED AS : `clickEventInfoBtn_CB(true)`**

we get `remove = true;`

and when,

**IT IS CALLED BY EVENTLISTNER:-**

we get `remove = PointerEvent {isTrusted: true, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …};`

Comment: Event listeners will always be executed with some parameters. Just because you've declared `remove = false` doesn't mean that the event handler will be called with a boolean - it's always passed an event. That's how all event handler callbacks are executed.

Comment: @VLAZ should I add a second argument with the name `event` so that eventListner will not add its event to my remove parameter??

Comment: The event is always passed as the first argument. You're better off not using a direct function reference `.addEventListener("click", () => clickEventInfoBtn_CB())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhandler always give the event as an argument to the callback function. So this would not work. You can easily change your code to fulfill your requirements in this way

```
infoBtnCB.addEventListener("click", () => { clickEventInfoBtn_CB(); });
function clickEventInfoBtn_CB(remove = false) {
  console.log(remove);
  if (remove) {
    infoBtnCB.classList.remove("active-info-btn-CB");
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.classList.toggle("active-info-btn-CB");
  }
  if (infoBtnCB.innerHTML == "Info" && !remove) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      infoBtnCB.innerHTML =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque accusamus ipsum, quidem harum similique blanditiis, veritatis nam sapiente tenetur rerum temporibus asperiores, commodi consequatur corporis quisquam aspernatur quas laudantium eaque.m";
    }, 100);
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.innerHTML = "Info";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah hah Nice and thanks, So we gonna put dirt in eventListner's eyes XD, Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When passing parameter values, use an "anonymous function" that calls the specified function with the parameters:

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(p) {
  p = false;
  myFunction(p);
});

function myFunction(a) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This answer would be better if the anonymous function contained a default argument - but it is called without any argument. This would show the OP that default arguments still work when a function is called without arguments in an event. code.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for an event listner function will be the event by which it was executed. So if you wnt to make the function call without the event object, you could make use of an arrow function, and the function call without the event.

```js
const infoBtnCB = document.getElementById("infoBtnCB");
infoBtnCB.addEventListener("click",(e) => clickEventInfoBtn_CB());
function clickEventInfoBtn_CB(remove = false) {
  console.log(remove);
  if (remove) {
    infoBtnCB.classList.remove("active-info-btn-CB");
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.classList.toggle("active-info-btn-CB");
  }
  if (infoBtnCB.innerHTML == "Info" && !remove) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      infoBtnCB.innerHTML =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque accusamus ipsum, quidem harum similique blanditiis, veritatis nam sapiente tenetur rerum temporibus asperiores, commodi consequatur corporis quisquam aspernatur quas laudantium eaque.m";
    }, 100);
  } else {
    infoBtnCB.innerHTML = "Info";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="infoBtnCB">Click Me</button>
```